# terraform GCP cloud function without having to deploy via terraform in CI or breaking past deployments when running locally?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I have some working terraform definitions among a larger project:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "owlee_functions_bucket" {
  name     = "owlee_functions_bucket"
  location = "europe-west2"
  project  = "owlee-software"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = "index.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.owlee_functions_bucket.name
  source = "../apps/backend/dist/index.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "backend_function" {
  name    = "backend_function"
  runtime = "nodejs16"
  project = "owlee-software"
  region  = "europe-west2"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.owlee_functions_bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = "OWLEE"
}
```

Then I'm trying to deploy via CI, for now, I'm just running `terraform apply` after zipping up the new version of the function to handle deployment.

It's not great and I'd like to change that to a non-terraform process ideally but that doesn't seem to be documented/possible anywhere which makes me think I have the wrong approach with this.

The second issue which is more urgent to solve --

I want to continue managing my infrastructure locally for now and do not want to have to zip up a new version of the function to deploy everytime I have to run `terraform apply` locally.

Is there a way -- after its creation -- to avoid overwriting/uploading the function via terraform?

I'm guessing this would be somewhat necessary for the CI deployment to work anyway.

I've looked at a handful of other SO threads but they were looking at specifics around cloud-build and the artifacts registry.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you deploy the cloud function by terraform but that the CI of the cloud function is maintained by a cloud build (also created by terraform) I think this is the most logical solution since terraform manages the infrastructure not the implementation of the cloud function.

Comment: that is indeed what I'm trying to do -- but currently the terraform configurations available and documentation do not suggest <how> to do it or if it is possible at all.

Comment: Yes, you can create cloud function and and cloud build. Where the cloud build deploy any update from code for the cloud function. If you want I can create a simple example for you.

Comment: I'd be eternally grateful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed name as you are, use a random string or depending on needs the commit hash for example. This can be prefixed with other things to make it even more unique.

```
resource "random_string" "function" {
  length           = 8
  special          = false
  
  keepers = {
    commit_hash = var.commit_hash,
    environment = var.environment,
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "archive" {
  name   = "index.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.owlee_functions_bucket.name
  source = "../apps/backend/dist/${random_string.function.result}.zip"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "backend_function" {
  name    = "backend_function"
  runtime = "nodejs16"
  project = "owlee-software"
  region  = "europe-west2"

  available_memory_mb   = 128
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.owlee_functions_bucket.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.archive.name
  trigger_http          = true
  entry_point           = "OWLEE"
}
```

This way if you provide an `environmnet` such as prod and the same commit hash every time, it will create the same zip file.

If you provide a new `environment`, say "local", it will generate a new zip. You can then create multiple instances of functions or make more changes to the  `google_cloudfunctions_function` so that it can be used with workspaces